Can't see iPhone 16 simulators on Xcode 16.1 beta
I have the latest Xcode 16.1 beta installed. I have the iOS 18.1 installed too. For some reasons, I don't see any iPhone 16 simulator in Xcode. I tried to install it, but Xcode simply didn't give me any iPhone 16 selection. The latest I can see is the iPhone 15 simulators.
Xcode screenshot next:

